# Como usar a versão 2.4.2 do Demoiselle?

Tags: demoiselle

Estou tentando usar o Demoiselle 2.4.2.

Declarei assim meu pom parent:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoiselle-servlet-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
</parent>
```

Também coloquei no meu pom a property

```
<demoiselle.framework.version>2.4.2</demoiselle.framework.version>
```

Mas na hora de subir o JBoss, dá esse erro:

> 10:27:34,342 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread
>   1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."sislv-ws.war".WeldStartService:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."sislv-ws.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start
>   service
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1936)
>   [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>       Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [HttpServletRequest] with
>   qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[parameter 1] of [method]
>   @Default @Produces public
>   br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.producer.HttpSessionProducer.create(HttpServletRequest)].
>   Possible dependencies [[Producer Method [HttpServletRequest] with
>   qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[method] @Default @Produces
>   public
>   br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.producer.HttpServletRequestProducer.create()],
>   Producer Method [HttpServletRequest] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
>   declared as [[method] @Default @Produces public
>   br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.producer.HttpServletRequestProducer.create()]]]
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:318)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:284)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:147)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:167)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:386)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:371)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:379)
>           at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:64)
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980)
>   [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913)
>   [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
>           ... 3 more

E também esse:

> 10:27:34,378 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread)
>   JBAS014774: Relatório
>        de status de serviço JBAS014777: Serviços que falham na inicialização:      service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."sislv-ws.war".WeldStartService:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."sislv-ws.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start
>   service

Tá errado a declaração do meu parent pom? Ou será que tá faltando alguma outra coisa?

Ah, minha seção de dependências:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.gov.serpro</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqladaj</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
        <artifactId>demoiselle-jpa</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
        <artifactId>demoiselle-jta</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: A declaração está correta sim. Você está fazendo upgrade da versão no projeto? Se sim, de qual versão está partindo? E qual versão do Jboss está usando? Tem como postar o POM.XML completo?

Comment: O projeto é novo, mas estou me baseando em outro projeto que era Demoiselle 2.4.0-BETA2

Comment: Ah, o JBoss é o EAP 6.3.

Comment: Seu projeto está passando o build? `mnv clean` ?

Comment: sim. mas o problema parece estar bem no Demoiselle, já que ele fala que uma classe produzida pelo Demoiselle está ambígua para o CDI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opa, o problema resolveu-se. Não sei direito o que pegou, mas algumas coisas que fiz:

- Adicionar o repositório

  ```
  <repository>
      <id>component.internal</id>
      <name>SERPRO Component Maven Repository</name>
      <url>http://archiva.desenv.serpro/repository/component-internal</url>
      <snapshots>
          <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
  </repository>
  ```
- E recompilar o projeto para que de fato algumas dependências fossem baixadas (eu estava fazendo só o update project do m2eclipse).

Comment: Tem algum jeito de marcar o post como resolvido?

Comment: A sua resposta já indica isso. Os "sem resposta" é que são considerados abertos.

Comment: @LeonardoLeite após 48 horas você mesmo pode marcar sua resposta como aceita, como indica [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

O repositório indicado é iterno do serpro e não está acessível:

http://archiva.desenv.serpro/repository/component-internal